# How can I add this function into my tip calculator?

Tags: javascript

I am new programmer trying to add a function in my tip calculator that informs the users of an uneven bill. For an example if 3 people were trying to split a bill of $100 who would pay the last cent?

I think I might be on the right path by making this function

```
function payTheDifference() {
total % 3 === 0 
return "someone needs to pay the difference 1 cent" }
```

but I am unable to add it in without conflicting with the current code I have.

Here is my HTML & JavaScript code

```js
const billInput = document.getElementById('billTotalInput');
const tipInput = document.getElementById('tipInput')
const numberOfPeopleDiv = document.getElementById('numberOfPeople');
const perPersonTotalDiv = document.getElementById('perPersonTotal');

let numberOfPeople = Number(numberOfPeopleDiv.innerText)

function payTheDifference() {
    total % 3 === 0 
    return "someone needs to pay the difference 1 cent"
}

const calculateBill = () => {
    const bill = Number(billInput.value);
    const tipPercent = Number(tipInput.value) / 100;
    const totalAmount = bill * tipPercent;
    const total = totalAmount + bill;
    
    const perPersonTotal = total / numberOfPeople;
    perPersonTotalDiv.innerText = `$${perPersonTotal.toFixed(2)}`
       
};

const increasePeople = () => {
    numberOfPeople += 1
    numberOfPeopleDiv.innerText = numberOfPeople
    calculateBill()
};

const decreasePeople = () => {
      if(numberOfPeople <= 1){
        return
            
    }
    numberOfPeople -= 1
    numberOfPeopleDiv.innerText = numberOfPeople
    calculateBill()

  

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Group Pay</h1>
      <p>Pay as a group! This app will calculate your total bill(With tip!) and allow you divide it evenly with your friends!</p>
      <div class="container" id="topContainer">
        <div class="title">Bill total</div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
          <span>$</span>
          <input
            onkeyup="calculateBill()"
            type="text"
            id="billTotalInput"
            placeholder="0.00"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="title">Tip</div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
          <span>%</span>
          <input
            onkeyup="calculateBill()"
            type="text"
            id="tipInput"
            placeholder="10"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container" id="bottom">
        <div class="splitContainer">
          <div class="title">People</div>
          <div class="controls">
            <span class="buttonContainer">
              <button class="splitButton" onclick="increasePeople()">
                <span class="buttonText">+</span>
              </button>
            </span>
            <span class="splitAmount" id="numberOfPeople">1</span>
            <span class="buttonContainer">
              <button class="splitButton" onclick="decreasePeople()">
                <span class="buttonText">-</span>
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="totalContainer">
          <div class="title">Total per Person</div>
          <div class="total" id="perPersonTotal">$0.00</div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="goBack">
          <a href="../index.html">
            <button class="back">Click me to go back to the home page</button>
          </a>
        </div> 
      
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>


</html>
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of `total % 3 === 0`. You should use it in an `if` statement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`payTheDifference()` should return the extra amount. Then `calculateBill()` can check if this is non-zero, and display it appropriately.

```js
const billInput = document.getElementById('billTotalInput');
const tipInput = document.getElementById('tipInput')
const numberOfPeopleDiv = document.getElementById('numberOfPeople');
const perPersonTotalDiv = document.getElementById('perPersonTotal');
const differenceContainerDiv = document.getElementById("differenceContainer");
const differenceDiv = document.getElementById("difference");

let numberOfPeople = Number(numberOfPeopleDiv.innerText)

function payTheDifference(total, persons) {
  return Math.round(total * 100) % persons;
}

const calculateBill = () => {
  const bill = Number(billInput.value);
  const tipPercent = Number(tipInput.value) / 100;
  const totalAmount = bill * tipPercent;
  const total = totalAmount + bill;

  const perPersonTotal = total / numberOfPeople;
  perPersonTotalDiv.innerText = `$${perPersonTotal.toFixed(2)}`
  const diff = payTheDifference(total, numberOfPeople);
  if (diff > 0) {
    differenceContainerDiv.style.display = 'block';
    differenceDiv.innerText = `${diff} cents`;
  } else {
    differenceContainerDiv.style.display = 'none';
  }
};

const increasePeople = () => {
  numberOfPeople += 1
  numberOfPeopleDiv.innerText = numberOfPeople
  calculateBill()
};

const decreasePeople = () => {
  if (numberOfPeople <= 1) {
    return
  }
  numberOfPeople -= 1
  numberOfPeopleDiv.innerText = numberOfPeople
  calculateBill()
};
```

```css
.differenceContainer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Group Pay</h1>
    <p>Pay as a group! This app will calculate your total bill(With tip!) and allow you divide it evenly with your friends!</p>
    <div class="container" id="topContainer">
      <div class="title">Bill total</div>
      <div class="inputContainer">
        <span>$</span>
        <input onkeyup="calculateBill()" type="text" id="billTotalInput" placeholder="0.00" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="title">Tip</div>
      <div class="inputContainer">
        <span>%</span>
        <input onkeyup="calculateBill()" type="text" id="tipInput" placeholder="10" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="bottom">
      <div class="splitContainer">
        <div class="title">People</div>
        <div class="controls">
          <span class="buttonContainer">
              <button class="splitButton" onclick="increasePeople()">
                <span class="buttonText">+</span>
          </button>
          </span>
          <span class="splitAmount" id="numberOfPeople">1</span>
          <span class="buttonContainer">
              <button class="splitButton" onclick="decreasePeople()">
                <span class="buttonText">-</span>
          </button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="totalContainer">
        <div class="title">Total per Person</div>
        <div class="total" id="perPersonTotal">$0.00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="differenceContainer" id="differenceContainer">
        <div class="title">Someone needs to pay the difference</div>
        <div class="total" id="difference">0 cents</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="goBack">
      <a href="../index.html">
        <button class="back">Click me to go back to the home page</button>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I kind of feel dumb for not seeing that the simple answer was just to use and If else to check if the remainder was > 0.